# no video supported format and mime type found

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Every time I watch a video on tor this message is displayed”no video supported format and mime type found”. How do you fix this I tried changing the security from high to normal it still did not work

Comment: it may be that it's using some non-standard video format, or it requires DRM that might compromise anonymity. Essentially, Tor Browser doesn't support whatever the website is offering. Does it work with Firefox ESR but not Tor Browser?

Comment: Yeah it works on Firefox and not tor

Comment: can we get around this DRM problem to play videos ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Ubuntu,
use the following commands as tor checks for the codecs supported by your system.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```